# php adodb StartTrans() is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

i am using adodb library for my php project

i am connecting to mySQL 5.5 with PHP 5.1

what i am trying to do is insert 5 SQL statement and 1 update. if just one of these fail..i want to rollback all statements..

this is my code

```
$ado->StartTrans();
$ado->exequte($sql1);
$ado->exequte($sql2);
$ado->exequte($sql3);
$ado->exequte($sql4);
$ado->exequte($sql5);
$ado->CompleteTrans();
```

but it seems like its not working. it just execute all SQL statement and will not rollback even if there is a failure(s)..

right now im just using plain old if statement.. if ok then proceed, else rollback.

the documentation of adodb about this is also not clear for me.

Comment: what do you mean `there is a failure(s)`? give us an example of failure

Comment: for example if $sql2 cannot run.. the result of $sql1 is still comitted.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different drivers for MySQL in ADOdb:

- mysql
- mysqlt

The first one (What you probably used) has no transaction support while the second one does.

Try using the mysqlt driver:

```
$conn = ADONewConnection("mysqlt");
```